# Can a player respond while a spell is resolving?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast [Wistful Thinking](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Wistful%20Thinking) on my opponent, whose hand has two Mountain cards. Wistful Thinking resolves and my opponent draws a [Shock](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shock) and another Mountain.

Can my opponent cast Shock before discarding it?

Comment: Do you mean "Can my opponent cast Shock before resolving the discard part of the effect"? Your opponent certainly cast cast Shock before discarding it, because once it's cast, it's not in the hand and therefore can't be discarded.

Comment: No, that is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, they can not cast the Shock.**

Comprehensive rule 608, all parts.

The fact that the card text contains 'then' does not make the two parts separate abilities. The whole effect of drawing, then discarding, happens in that order while the spell resolves. There is time in between drawing and discarding for the new information to be reacted upon. However, there is no break in the resolution.

There is no passing of priority until the spell completely resolves, and thus no opportunity to cast the instant.

Edit June 2018:

In regards to the Madness key word and abilities:

A Madness trigger may cause someone to believe that in response to a card being discarded the 'Madness' ability interrupts the resolution of the thing on the stack that would trigger madness. This is not the case.

Rule 702.34 which defines Madness has this to say:

> 702.34a Madness is a keyword that represents two abilities. The first is a static ability that functions while the card with madness is in a
>   player’s hand. The second is a triggered ability that functions when
>   the first ability is applied. “Madness [cost]” means “If a player
>   would discard this card, that player discards it, but exiles it
>   instead of putting it into their graveyard” and “When this card is
>   exiled this way, its owner may cast it by paying [cost] rather than
>   paying its mana cost. If that player doesn’t, they put this card into
>   their graveyard."

Though it is not explicitly stated here, this does not cause the player who's card is exiled to receive priority at that time. The card is in exile and when the player who exiled the card has priority again, they are able to choose to cast the card(s) in exile or let it(them) go into the graveyard.

Comment: The whole effect doesn't happen at once, first two cards are drawn, then a moment later four cards are discarded, even if they are part of the same ability. Still, this rarely matters, because nothing can be played in between both actions.

Comment: good point. the use of 'at once' is a bit inaccurate since they would happen in order and there would be time in between the two actions for the player to react.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "react", there is no time in which a player gets priority, so a player can't actually "do" anything in between.

Comment: by 'reacted upon' I mean they get to decide which of the cards now in their hand, including the ones they just drew, will be discarded.

Comment: Different question but related (and I know this is an old answer), might be worth mentioning the [Madness](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Madness) mechanic as that might be a not so uncommon situation where newer players might think something is being "responded" to mid resolution.

Comment: @Malco that is very fair. I added the rules text and a brief about it.