# Can I respond to a draw from Gitaxan probe?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

If I resolve a [Gitaxian Probe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gitaxian%20Probe), can I crack a [Lion Eye Diamond](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lion%20Eye%20Diamond) before I draw?

Comment: I do not agree that this is a duplicate. Without more clarification, it doesn't sound to me like he is asking literally about responding while a spell is resolving; but rather that he poorly chose that wording without knowing the proper terminology. If it just said "cast" instead of "resolve", then it would have nothing to do with that other question, and would be answered by the answers here.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to activate [Lions Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLions%20Eye%20Diamond%5d) before drawing a card, you must do so before [Gitaxian Probe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGitaxian%20Probe%5d) resolves.

You can respond to another event, like your opponent playing a spell or activating an ability.

So no, there is no opportunity to respond to your spell once it has begun resolving. You will get priority after the spell resolves, and at that time you can activate your Lion's Eye Diamond.

See this question for more details:  [Can a player respond while a spell is resolving?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12535/can-a-player-respond-while-a-spell-is-resolving?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

Not as you have written, while [Gitaxian Probe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gitaxian%20Probe) is resolving no one can do anything since no one has priority.

However you could cast [Gitaxian Probe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gitaxian%20Probe), hold priority, and then activate [Lion's Eye Diamond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383000), thus you will get to draw after discarding your hand because [Gitaxian Probe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gitaxian%20Probe) has not resolved yet (as you did not pass priority). This won't allow you to look at your opponent's hand before deciding of course.

Comment: To be fair, Lion's Eye Diamond activation is a mana ability, thus not using the stack, so your second to last comment is a bit misleading.

Comment: Actually, discarding is part of the cost of activating LED, so the whole stack/mana ability discussion is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @Guvante The point is "get to draw after discarding your hand because spells and abilities resolve in the reverse order they are cast or activated" is implying that Lion's Eye Diamond uses the stack at all, which it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you're wanting, you'll have to do as follows:

1) Cast Gitaxian Probe

2) Before passing priority to your opponent, activate Lion's Eye Diamond

3) Once you discard your hand and get your mana, Gitaxian Probe will remain on the stack (and can resolve as normal).

---

The important thing is to remember to immediately **activate Lion's Eye as soon as you cast Gitaxian Probe** (BEFORE passing priority to your opponent, otherwise it will be too late (unless he responds to gitaxian probe).