# Are the two steps of Ponder an atomic action?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are a number of cards that have two different actions.  [Ponder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ponder) is one of them.  I assume these separate actions are in sequence, and cannot be responded to by placing items on the stack in between the steps.  But, I can't confirm that in the rules.

Game situation in which this came up (in case this helps explain *why* one would want to do this.)

I have a [Lion Eye Diamond](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lion%20Eye%20Diamond) on the table, and I cast [Ponder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ponder).  Ponder resolves, I draw my three cards, and put them back on top of the deck.  The top of the library is now a game winner if I can get 3 more mana.  [Say it's [Coalition Victory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Coalition%20Victory) but I only have RWGUB available and meet all other requirements] So, would like to fire off the Lion's Eye Diamond before I perform the second step of Ponder and draw that card.

Note: Lion's Eye Diamond can only be activated at instant speed (see the link) even though in all other ways it is a mana source.

Can I win this game this turn?  [assuming no counter spells of course...]

Comment: Thank you jwodder for pointing out the duplicate.  I was certain I had seen this before, but couldn't remember where.

Comment: Note that even if Lion's Eye Diamond **didn't** have that restriction, you still wouldn't be able to activate it at that time. Mana abilities can be activated whenever you have priority, *or* when you need to pay a mana cost, but this situation doesn't match either of those.

Comment: The answers to [Can I respond to a draw from Gitaxan probe?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23189/6692) also answer this question.